# C# Collision test of a ship and asteriod

Tags: c#

We are trying to to do a collision detection for the ship and asteroid.
If success than it should detect the collision before N turns. 
However it is confused between angle 350 and 15 and it is not really working.
Sometimes it is moving but sometime it is not moving at all.
On the other hand, it is not shooting at the right time as well.

I just want to ask how to make the collision detection working???
And how to solve the angle confusion problem?

```
            // Get velocities of asteroid


            Console.WriteLine("lol");

            // IF equation is between -2 and -3
            if (equation1a <= -2)
            {
                // Calculate no. turns till asteroid hits
                float turns_till_hit = dx / vx;

                // Calculate angle of asteroid
                float asteroid_angle_rad = (float)Math.Atan(Math.Abs(dy / dx));
                float asteroid_angle_deg = (float)(asteroid_angle_rad * 180 / Math.PI);

                float asteroid_angle = 0;

                // Calculate angle if asteroid is in certain positions
                if (asteroid.Y > ship.Y && asteroid.X > ship.X)
                {
                    asteroid_angle = asteroid_angle_deg; 
                }
                else if (asteroid.Y < ship.Y && asteroid.X > ship.X)
                {
                    asteroid_angle = (360 - asteroid_angle_deg);
                }
                else if (asteroid.Y < ship.Y && asteroid.X < ship.X)
                {
                    asteroid_angle = (180 + asteroid_angle_deg);
                }
                else if (asteroid.Y > ship.Y && asteroid.X < ship.X)
                {
                    asteroid_angle = (180 - asteroid_angle_deg);
                }

                // IF turns till asteroid hits are less than 35
                if (turns_till_hit < 50)
                {
                    float angle_between = 0;

                    // Calculate angle between if asteroid is in certain positions
                    if (asteroid.Y > ship.Y && asteroid.X > ship.X)
                    {
                        angle_between = ship_angle - asteroid_angle;
                    }
                    else if (asteroid.Y < ship.Y && asteroid.X > ship.X)
                    {
                        angle_between = (360 - Math.Abs(ship_angle - asteroid_angle));
                    }
                    else if (asteroid.Y < ship.Y && asteroid.X < ship.X)
                    {
                        angle_between = ship_angle - asteroid_angle;
                    }
                    else if (asteroid.Y > ship.Y && asteroid.X < ship.X)
                    {
                        angle_between = ship_angle - asteroid_angle;
                    }

                    // If angle less than 0, add 360
                    if (angle_between < 0)
                    {
                        //angle_between %= 360;
                        angle_between = Math.Abs(angle_between);
                    }

                    // Calculate no. of turns to face asteroid
                    float turns_to_face = angle_between / 25;

                    if (turns_to_face < turns_till_hit)
                    {
                        float ship_angle_left = ShipAngle(ship_angle, "leftKey", 1);

                        float ship_angle_right = ShipAngle(ship_angle, "rightKey", 1);

                        float angle_between_left = Math.Abs(ship_angle_left - asteroid_angle);

                        float angle_between_right = Math.Abs(ship_angle_right - asteroid_angle);

                        if (angle_between_left < angle_between_right)
                        {
                            leftKey = true;
                        }
                        else if (angle_between_right < angle_between_left)
                        {
                            rightKey = true;
                        }

                    }

                    if (angle_between > 0 && angle_between < 25)
                    {
                        spaceKey = true;
                    }
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: and you expect us to do what?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question. This is a question-and-answer site. You've stated a bunch of requirements and said that you have bugs; those are not questions. Is there a question you have about those requirements or the bugs?

Comment: I had just edited it a bit...

Comment: @gbianchi find the bugs and correct the code :)

Comment: haha wow. This is a potentially HUGE question. You need to refine your post quite a lot. So much wrong with this code aswell. spaceKey, leftKey etc. should all ideally be named in accordance with what they 'toggle'. spaceKeyVisible for example.

Comment: @@ Sorry I don't understand........

Answer (score 11):

> How to make the collision detection working?

1. Find a reproducible scenario that does not work correctly.
2. Work out *by hand* the correct calculations for that scenario.
3. Start your program in the debugger. Watch the program perform those calculations.
4. When you reach a calculation that does not match the correct calculation that you worked out by hand, that's where the bug is.

In particular, look for places where the comments do not match the code; those are likely to be wrong. For example, this bit:

```
// If angle less than 0, add 360
if (angle_between < 0)
{
    angle_between = Math.Abs(angle_between); 
}
```

The comment says one thing and the code does something completely different. It is the code that actually runs.

And a word of advice: do all your calculations in doubles. There is no reason to keep casting doubles down to floats. Your making your program slower and less accurate by doing so. Also consider doing all your calculations in radians rather than converting back and forth between radians and degrees.

Also I note that you have plenty of opportunities for divisions by zero in your code. Those are likely to be bugs.

Comment: But how to use radians? I thought it is always degrees?

Comment: @CherryMa: The `Math` functions all use radians.