# Detect if objects are going to collide in 2D space

Tags: c#, trigonometry, angle

I've been trying to make an AI for an asteroids game but have become stuck.  Everything else in the game is set up (i.e. asteroids created and going in random directions, collision detection, ship and bullets.)  The AI is looped through every 150ms and can only tell the ship to turn left, turn right, move up and shoot.

Here's a snippet of my code that I'm using so far:

```
                // Convert points to positive
                float asteroid_x = Math.Abs(asteroid.X);
                float asteroid_y = Math.Abs(asteroid.Y);

                float ship_x = Math.Abs(ship.X);
                float ship_y = Math.Abs(ship.Y);

                // Calculate difference in X and Y using positive values
                float dx = asteroid_x - ship_x;
                float dy = asteroid_y - ship_y;

                // Get velocities of asteroid
                float vx = asteroid.VX;
                float vy = asteroid.VY;
```

Using these variables (dx, dy, vx, vy) I need to calculate if the asteroid is going to hit the ship. I've been trying to use trigonometry but it keeps thinking it's going to hit when it isn't.  The equations that I've been trying to use are:

```
            float equation1a = (dy / vy) - (dx / vx);
            float equation1 = ((dy / dx) - (vy / vx));
```

I've then been trying to use an IF statement to determine whether it's going to hit or not but I'm not sure how to go about it properly.  After this IF statement I then want to go into the AI to either turn and shoot the asteroid or evade it.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: The X and Y values for the ship or the asteroid can also be negative, with the ship starting on the origin (0,0).

EDIT2: Got a bit further with it all now and come up with this:

```
// Determine if asteroid will collide
int turns_ahead = 100;
bool collision = false;
int least_turns = 500;
for (int i = 0; i < turns_ahead; i++)
{
    PointF asteroid_pos_next = NextPosition(new PointF(asteroid.X, asteroid.Y), new PointF(asteroid.VX, asteroid.VY), i);

    if (asteroid.CollidesWith(asteroid_pos_next.X, asteroid_pos_next.Y, ship.R))
    {
        collision = true;
    }
}
```

And the next position is worked out with this function:

```
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Function to find position of object in X turns (turns_ahead)
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    private static PointF NextPosition(PointF current_pos, PointF velocity, int turns_ahead)
    {
        float next_x_pos = current_pos.X + (velocity.X * turns_ahead);

        float next_y_pos = current_pos.Y + (velocity.Y * turns_ahead);

        // IFs to deal with screen wrap-around
        if (next_x_pos < -Form1.maxX)
        {
            next_x_pos = Form1.maxX;
            if (next_y_pos < 0)
                next_y_pos += Form1.maxY;
            else
                next_y_pos -= Form1.maxY;
        }
        else if (next_x_pos > Form1.maxX)
        {
            next_x_pos = -Form1.maxX;
            if (next_y_pos < 0)
                next_y_pos += Form1.maxY;
            else
                next_y_pos -= Form1.maxY;
        }

        if (next_y_pos < -Form1.maxY)
        {
            next_y_pos = Form1.maxY;
            if (next_x_pos < 0)
                next_x_pos += Form1.maxX;
            else
                next_x_pos -= Form1.maxX;
        }
        else if (next_y_pos > Form1.maxY)
        {
            next_y_pos = -Form1.maxY;
            if (next_x_pos < 0)
                next_x_pos += Form1.maxX;
            else
                next_x_pos -= Form1.maxX;
        }

        PointF next_pos = new PointF(next_x_pos, next_y_pos);

        return next_pos;
    }
```

the collidesWith is a function of the asteroid class and is used elsewhere to detect if a bullet/ship has hit into an asteroid.  I'm not sure whether my next position function is correct though as if the asteroid does wrap around the X/Y value seems to get stuck at the maxX/maxY value?

Comment: This as absolutely nothing to do with AI (not at all).

Comment: Is this a class project? I just saw a similar question earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773255/c-sharp-collision-test-of-a-ship-and-asteriod

Comment: The AI part comes in when the ship has to move out of the way/shoot.  And yes it is part of a class project, sorry I probably should have said.  My Lecturer had given us the wrong formulas to work with so had gotten pretty confused, seem to have it working now though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following: at any moment you have the position of the asteroid and the ship and their velocities. Then, at a time t (intervals of 150ms), the position of asteroid will be

```
asteroid_x + asteroid.vx * t
asteroid_y + asteroid.vy * t
```

and the position of the ship will be

```
ship_x + ship.vx * t
ship_y + ship.vy * t
```

So you can just iterate through t (0 to 100) and check if at any time the asteroid and the ship are within some distance (e.g. the sum of their radii) of each other - which means a collision.

p.s. the distance is given by

```
sqrt( (asteroid_x - ship_x)^2 + (astroid_y - ship_y)^2 )
```

I suggest you read more about collision detection in general as well

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough context here, need to see more code really. The very very high-level concept I'd be working on though is two steps - 1. moving the asteroid object (on a different thread to the user/AI moving the ship), 2. checking the position of the asteroid in comparison to the position of the ships (for a collision) on every movement (event handler). Also - you mention 'going to hit it', are you trying to predict a collision before it happens? If so, you'd need to take into account the previous/most recent movements of the asteroid and the ship to 'forecast' their future movements.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the motions of your objects in 3 dimensions, where the third is time; they will eventually collide if these lines-in-3D come close enough together (less than the sum of their radii, assuming the objects are both circles).

These two 3D lines may be defined by the point (x,y,0) and the direction vector (vx,vy,1); you can then apply well-known geometry to find the closest distance between two "skew" 3D lines; I don't know it offhand but [here's an article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line-LineDistance.html) which gives

> D = |c · (a × b)| / |a × b|

where the lowercase variables are vectors, c is the difference between positions, and *a* and *b* are the two direction vectors.

Note that this will produce a false positive if the objects *would have collided in the past* on their current trajectories; I don't know offhand how to fix that, but even if you left that in it probably wouldn't interfere with your AI much. Perhaps there's a way to test for "definitely moving apart", or perhaps the sign of the numerator in that formula is meaningful.